# Thud-like sound coming from AC Window Unit

Tags: hvac

I have this very old AC Window unit. I service it every year without issues, though this year after servicing it, it worked fine for around a month but the cooling got reduced a bit. My main issue with the cooling, at the moment. It is the sound it makes. It makes a thud-like sound every 5-10 seconds (one second thud-like sound like a pulse). The sound is very low pitch and it is like bass vibration coming from large speakers. I can feel like the sound like it is vibrating my body.

The technician said he cannot hear it. Though, the sound is there and it is driving me crazy. I tried placing a pillow above my head and I can still hear/feel this sound because it is low pitched.

I would appreciate any information you can give me. Note that this sound also happens on fan mode (no cooling) at around 15-25 seconds per sound.

Comment: Ask for a second opinion. Or it is time to retire this unit.

Comment: It is likely the compressor cycling on and off - far too frequently. Perhaps it's overheating due to loss of refrigerant, bad bearings, etc. It is likely far cheaper to get a new window AC than to fix an old unit. It may be some consolation that newer AC's can be more energy efficient, using less electricity and costing less monthly. Choose an energy-efficient unit.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It is much appreciated. r13 I asked for someone to check it out, but they refuse to acknowledge the issue. It seems I have super sonic ears or something. I am being sarcastic ofc :\. DrMoishe Pippik, sadly I cannot afford to replace the unit at the moment. I will be able to replace it within 3 months when I have money. So, I am trying to make the most of it for now. Sadly, I cannot sleep. On fan mode, the issue is there. Is the compressor connected to the fan in any way that it works while the fan mode is on?